# My PHP datetime code doesn't work properly

Tags: php

The code shown below isn't working properly, can you tell me why that is? My web browser shows a 504 error when loading the script.

I tried many ways to fix it. It just cannot access any datetime object. Even though I copy the code from php manual.

Is there another way, I could possibly write this line like?

```
<?php
        
$start = new DateTime('2012-07-01');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Create a DateTimeImmutable Object is ok

```
$date = new DateTimeImmutable('2000-01-01');
```

Comment: Doesn't really explain why the OP's code isn't working, which it should.

Comment: @j08691 They are the OP.

Comment: @ethry Then this should probably be an edit to the question, not an answer.